Moving map to the center after folding the sidebar
I was wondering how to make my leaflet map displayed slightly to right with using css, so I won't have to set setview or center values for that. After I fold the sidebar I want the map to come back to center of the site. I tried something with add left:10% to leaflet.css but it messes with the coords popup.
function setupMap() {
    let mapData; // Zmienna do przechowywania danych mapy

    // Pobranie bieżącej ścieżki URL
    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

    // Sprawdzenie ścieżki i ustawienie odpowiednich wartości
    if (currentPath.includes('/white_orchard/')) {
        mapData = mapdata_wo; // Użyj danych z mapdata_wo
    } else if (currentPath.includes('/velen_novigrad/')) {
        mapData = mapdata_vn; // Użyj danych z mapdata_vn
    } else {
        console.error('Nieznana ścieżka mapy');
        return;
    }

    var bounds = L.latLngBounds(mapData.sWest, mapData.nEast);
    var map = L.map('mapid', {
        zoomControl: false,
        center: mapData.map_center, // Ustawienie poprawnych współrzędnych (lat, lng)
        zoom: mapData.map_zoom,
        maxZoom: mapData.max_zoom,
        minZoom: mapData.min_zoom,
        attributionControl: false,
        zoomSnap: 0.5,  // Umożliwia zoom co 0.5
        zoomDelta: 0.5,
        maxBounds: bounds,
        maxBoundsViscosity: 0,
        fullscreenControl: true
    });

    function addBoundaryLine() {
        var corners = [
            [mapData.sWest.lat, mapData.sWest.lng],  // Dolny lewy róg
            [mapData.nEast.lat, mapData.sWest.lng],  // Górny lewy róg
            [mapData.nEast.lat, mapData.nEast.lng],  // Górny prawy róg
            [mapData.sWest.lat, mapData.nEast.lng],  // Dolny prawy róg
            [mapData.sWest.lat, mapData.sWest.lng]   // Zamknięcie obwodu (powrót do dolnego lewego rogu)
        ];

        // Dodanie polilinii (linii wielokątnej) z czerwoną linią
        var boundaryLine = L.polyline(corners, {
            color: 'red',   // Kolor linii
            weight: 2,      // Grubość linii
            opacity: 1      // Przezroczystość
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    // Wywołanie funkcji po załadowaniu mapy
    addBoundaryLine();

    // Dodanie kontrolek zoomu
    L.control.zoom({
        position: 'bottomright',
        zoomInTitle: 'Przybliż',
        zoomOutTitle: 'Oddal'
    }).addTo(map);

    // Okienko z koordynatami
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        var coords = e.latlng;
        var lat = coords.lat.toFixed(5);
        var lng = coords.lng.toFixed(5);
        console.log('Map clicked at:', lat, lng);
        L.popup()
            .setLatLng(coords)
            .setContent("Koordynaty: " + lat + ", " + lng)
            .openOn(map);
    });

    // Dodanie warstwy kafelków z opcją TMS
    L.tileLayer(mapData.map_path + '.jpg', {
        tms: true, // Ustawienie odwrotnej numeracji kafelków
        noWrap: true,
        bounds: bounds,
        maxZoom: mapData.max_zoom,
        minZoom: mapData.min_zoom,
        continousWorld: true,
    }).addTo(map);
}


// Wywołanie funkcji po załadowaniu DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    setupMap();
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
    const image = document.getElementById('toggleImage');
    const hideableDiv = document.getElementById('hideableDiv');
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('mapid');

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const isHidden = hideableDiv.style.display === 'none';
        if (isHidden) {
            hideableDiv.style.display = 'block'; // Pokazuje div
            image.src = '/resources/images/cc_greaterthan-left.png'; // Zmienia obrazek
        } else {
            hideableDiv.style.display = 'none'; // Ukrywa div
            image.src = '/resources/images/cc_greaterthan-right.png';
        }
        // if (mapElement.classList.contains('map-move-left')) {
        //     mapElement.classList.remove('map-move-left');
        // } else {
        //     mapElement.classList.add('map-move-left');
        // }
    });
});

function showCategory(category) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.text-box').forEach((cat) => {
        cat.style.display = (category === 'all' || cat.id === category) ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const rightToggleButton = document.getElementById('rightToggleButton');
    const rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');
    const secondRightToggleButton = document.getElementById('secondRightToggleButton');
    const secondRightContent = document.getElementById('secondRightContent');

    rightToggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const buttonRect = rightToggleButton.getBoundingClientRect();
        rightContent.style.top = (buttonRect.top - 10) + 'px';
        rightContent.style.display = rightContent.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        secondRightContent.style.display = 'none'; // Ukryj drugie okienko
    });

    secondRightToggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const buttonRect = secondRightToggleButton.getBoundingClientRect();
        secondRightContent.style.top = (buttonRect.top - 10) + 'px';
        secondRightContent.style.display = secondRightContent.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        rightContent.style.display = 'none'; // Ukryj pierwsze okienko
    });
});


Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

You can use something like padding-left: 100px or margin-left: 5% to move elements to right but always start with lower values and then increase as you need so you can understand how much you need. if you use high values it messes your UI.

I don't feel like writing. Here's my example of how to center a map fitBounds-with-padding
